# find certain files using glob pattern

Tags: ruby, regex, path, glob, logstash

I'm using `logstash` to constantly look for a new files and stream the data to a different systems.

Right now I'm using this config:

```
input {

  file {
    type => "source"
    path => "/ebs/**/*-*csv"  # recursivly check subfolders
    sincedb_path => "/usr/local/logstash/sincedb"
    sincedb_write_interval => 1
    discover_interval => 4
    start_position => "beginning"
    stat_interval => 1
  }
}
```

It works fine but what I want to do is something like this:

```
path => "/ebs/**/*-[0-9]{10}.csv"
```

Is it possible to include regex like this in the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash [File](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/inputs/file#path) Input api only supports [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)([Wildcard](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)), as Unix shells support. For example, if you list files in Unix system by using glob pattern,

> $ ls [0-9].csv

It can show the file "1.csv"

But when you add regular expression,

> $ ls [0-9]{1}.csv

The system shows

> ls: [0-9]{1}.csv: No such file or directory

So, If you want to add regular expression, maybe you need to match [globbing pattern](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm). 
Such as

> path => "/ebs/*/*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv"

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Rake::FileList`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html), it fits perfectly from the job:

```
require rake
FileList.new("/ebs/**/*-[0-9]{10}.csv")
```

Should do the job for you

Comment: This makes sense. But for this I assume I will need to modify the source and recompile the code. which is not really an option in my situation. I was looking to some logstash specific solution.

Comment: sorry for the lack of information. `logstash` is written in `JRuby`

Comment: @Vor I would look at the source later today and see if I can submit a patch

Comment: @Vor not sure what exactly was used in the project, checked today and on IRC, but if it is `Dir.glob` then I assume it has a similar behavior with `Rake::FileList`, you can try your pattern and see if it does not give issues, if it does then you can go on irc #logstash or drop a comment and I would have a look

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately this regex doesn't work in `logstash`. Tried, a suggestion from another answer and it works.